# How to get foreign key in views from django template?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I'm unable get the field name under cleaned_data for the form, as the field is coming under data for request.POST

views.py

```py
def newProjectView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        projectForm = ProjectInsertionForm(request.POST)
        if projectForm.is_valid():
            jobDesc = projectForm.save(commit=False)
            jobDesc.save()
            messages.success(request, message="Succefully saved the Project.")
            return redirect('accounts:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, message='Unable to save the project, Please do check the details. \n%s \n%s' % (projectForm.cleaned_data, projectForm.data))
            return redirect('accounts:profile')
```

forms.py

```py
class ProjectInsertionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyDesc
        fields = ('companyDets', 'title', 'details')
```

models.py

```py
class CompanyDesc(models.Model):
    companyDets = models.ForeignKey(CompanyList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    details = models.TextField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

work.html

```html
<p>
                                    <form action="{% url 'accounts:newProject' %}" method="POST">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <p><input type="text" name="companyDets" id="id_companyDets" value="{{ company.company }}" class="col-md-12" style="border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #d32878; padding: 5px;"></p>
                                        <p><input type="text" name="title" id="id_title" class="col-md-12" style="border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #d32878; padding: 5px;"></p>
                                        <p><input type="text" name="details" id="id_details" class="col-md-12" style="border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #d32878; padding: 5px;"></p>

                                        <p><input type="submit" class="razo-btn" value="Save Job"></p>
                                    </form>
</p>
```

In this example title and details are showing under cleaned data, but companyDets attribute was not in the cleaned data

Finally in the views, form.is_valid() returning False and going to the else block

Am I doing anything wrong...?

Comment: I added what will work below, but I need you to add the CompanyList modal if you need to know how to save the last of the code in views. I don't know the query which the ForeignKey of CompanyDesc connects with in CompanyList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the form than. 
forms

```
Class ProjectInsertionForm(forms.Form): 
companyDets = forms.CharField(max_length=202) 
title = forms.CharField(max_length=202) 
details = forms.CharField(max_length=202)
```

views

```
if form.is_valid():
    foo1 = form.cleaned_data.get("companyDets")
    foo2 = form.cleaned_data.get("title")
    foo3 = form.cleaned_data.get("details")
    obj = CompanyList.objects.get(***whatever field is in CompanyList Modal*** = foo1)
    obj2 = CompanyDesc(companyDets = obj, details = foo2, title=foo3)
    obj2.save()

    messages.success(request, message="Succefully saved the Project.")
    return redirect('accounts:profile')
```

html

```
<p>
    <form action="{% url 'accounts:newProject' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="text" name="companyDets" id="id_companyDets" class="col-md-12" style="border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #d32878; padding: 5px;"></p>
        <p><input type="text" name="title" id="id_title" class="col-md-12" style="border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #d32878; padding: 5px;"></p>
        <p><input type="text" name="details" id="id_details" class="col-md-12" style="border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #d32878; padding: 5px;"></p>

        <p><input type="submit" class="razo-btn" value="Save Job"></p>
    </form>
</p>
```

Comment: Do we need to pass fields if we set the custom models?

Comment: One more doubt... If in model, details attribute in TextField, how can I declare details in form?
I tried with forms.Textarea and forms.Textinput

Comment: Not sure what you question is. You can send the form through views and put {{ form }} between the <form> </form> tags. This will give all the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

In models:

```
companyDets = models.ForeignKey(CompanyList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='foo')
```

In html:

```
<p><input type="text" name="foo" id="id_companyDets">
```

try that

Comment: Yes now it entered the if condition but gave a new error
  File "E:\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line
85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py"
, line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: homeSplash_companydesc.
companyDets_id
[05/May/2019 19:36:57] "POST /accounts/newProject/ HTTP/1.1" 500 152861

Comment: That's because you are sending a string with the input, and trying to save it as an Object.

Comment: Sorry, nothing changed after this update... its my code changes that cause the above issue

Comment: Yes. Your input type is text, which works for the 2nd two values, but renders the form invalid when you send the first value, the 'CompanyDets' field. You are sending a string (text), not an object, which is what the modal is expecting to save. You have to catch the string on the backend, get the object from the CompanyList, and than save it like I did below. Can you post the CompanyList Modal? Would make things much easier to explain.

Comment: That's not the problem... the condition still not accepting the valid form... with your 'foo' example

Comment: Because the form is invalid. Instead of If form.isvalid(),use: if request.method == 'POST':

Comment: request.method == 'POST' is already there in the view. And everytime when I run that view its going to the else block of validForm

Comment: class ProjectInsertionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    companyDets = forms.CharField(max_length=202)  title = forms.CharField(max_length=202)                               details = forms.CharField(max_length=202)

Comment: And also when just print the form.cleaned_data, companyDets is not there in the dictionary. Its returning this
Unable to save the project, Please do check the details. {'title': 'Asset Dev', 'details': 'Test'}

Comment: CompanyDets will not be there as long as your Modal has it as a foreignkey and you are trying to send it through a form. Again, you can not send a string (input type=text) for a ForeignKey, because a ForeignKey is looking for an object, not a string. You can change the form to accept a string, as I just did, than the form will come up as valid, and you can proceed to save.

Comment: So I can't use form.is_valid if I use foreign key? I need to manually save the details assigning?

Comment: No, you can, but you have to change your forms. Try what I just edited in my original reply. I changed your forms to looks for a ChrField instead of a Obj. form.is_valid should work now.